# How to approach to setting passwords of a bunch of excel files(shared on dropbox)?

Tags: c#, excel, cloud, dropbox

The issue that I am running into is setting the password changes the binary of the excel. So this means that the file has to be downloaded on every computer it is being shared with. Now the problem is that aggregate size of these files is way more than the bandwidth I can hold up. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Won't dropbox just shift the file diffs?

Comment: nope it doesnt. because the excel is encrypted and hence the binary changes too. dropbox is just concerned with the superficial changes(for instance renaming), it doesn't go that deep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you change the password so often,? If it's for security, did you know that  Excel passwords are not secure. You can just open the file in XML and extract the password text in a few minutes after some googling. (or download a paid / free app that does it for you)

That being said, changing the password **WILL** change the xml of the excel, and dropbox **WILL** resync. there's no way around that bit with your current setup.

However, To address the bandwidth problem. it sounds as if you have multiple computers on the same network so this dropbox update is maxing out your bandwidth.
To that, I'd recommend turning on Dropbox's *'Lan Sync'* feature, so that all the computers on the network will update form each other, rather than uploading it to dropbox, and redownloading it X times.

[image: Dropbox Lan Sync]

If your computers are not on the same network, you'll likely need to drop dropbox and switch to an alternative file hosting method.

Comment: what else alternative do i have other than excel? i'm open to other more secure and efficient formats, just that file size should not be more than that of excel.

Comment: Alternative hosting would be to set up one machine to host the file, and have all he machines connect to the file remotely.
Alternative (more secure) ways to store the data would be to keep it in a database. For example with a Mysql database you can control usernames, passwords, and even what computers are allowed to use which accounts. This may be overkill for your project though so i'd recommend tryign to centralize the file hosting instead of duplicating it across the computers if the 'lan sync' doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: @Gimp +1 for the great tip with the LAN sync - did not know about that. And to Abmer, I am with Gimp on the point, that replacing Dropbox is easier than somehow replacing all your Excel-Files. You would just need some own Networkspace (NAS or a Server), SVN or Git for the version/access control, and a VPN or some other Networkaccess.

Comment: What if I serialize and then keep my data in a compressed format on the dropbox itself?